# Merge Typescript types, one of them optional

Tags: typescript

I have 2 TypeScript interfaces declaring some properties and look for ways to merge them.

```
interface fooUrls {
   url1: string,
   url2: string
}

interface barUrls {
    urlA: string,
    urlB: string
}
```

Now I would like to merge both interfaces, but make one set of `urls` optional. How I do that? I tried using `Partial<T>` but somehow don't find the correct form. The result should look like this:

```
interface fooBarUrls {
    url1?: string,
    url2?: string,
    urlA: string,
    urlB: string
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use partial. what do you mean by ` but somehow don't find the correct form`?

Comment: How do I use Partial? I never had to use it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `extends Partial<fooUrls>` like this:

```
   interface fooUrls {
       url1: string,
       url2: string
    }
    
    interface barUrls {
        urlA: string,
        urlB: string
    }
    
    interface fooBarUrls extends Partial<fooUrls> {
        urlA: string,
        urlB: string
    }
```

And the usage would be:

```
let f: fooBarUrls = {url1:'a', urlA:'urlA', urlB: 'urlB'}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=58&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhgezQVSgGwM7IDeAUMmQK64CMAXMnmFKAOYA0pFuATHQ0yM2IBfYsVCRYiFACM4UbPiIdOOAIK9GLdmRUAhDf0Eix4aPCSoMuuQoIQAHpBAATAsgAKcsMDg4APOhYuHgAfEo6yJRqBlrKkbj69JoCwqI4EGCodIHW8sHIALxEUbQA5HClrPHRpVGqldWJtQmlQkA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this not what I want. It introduces a urls property. I still want to access the properties directly.  ``fooBar.url1`` instead of ``fooBar.urls.url1``

Comment: Damn. I already do that and had hope to find a more elegant way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Reynicke I updated my answer see this exactly you want. you can extend from `Partial<fooUrls>`